# Violet UML Editor doesn't start on mac

Tags: java, uml, sourceforge

I am using eclipse for a coding course at school, and I am required to install Violet UML Editor http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php to create PDF of classes.

Anyway, I downloaded a .jar file. My mac doesn't like that it's from an unverified developer so I must manually allow it to open in system preferences. The .jar opens to the loading tab but it wont open the program.

'''Javac -version''' in terminal says javac 16.02. As far as I know, JDK holds JRE which I need to run Violet. To be safe I installed JRE from Oracle which was a JDK 8 file but it didn't work so I just deleted it.

[image: Image of the Loader]

UPDATE: Using terminal and entering '''java -jar violetumleditor-3.0.0.jar''' I get the error code

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile violetumleditor-3.0.0.jar
```

the .jar is located on my desktop, it should be found

Also yes I did a fresh 3.0 version install to try and the same thing.

UPDATE 2:
`java -version` gives

```
java version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7-67)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7-67, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thinking it's a permission with accessing desktop issue.

Comment: How did you try to run it though? Try this, open your console and type in this and hit enter: java -jar violetumleditor-3.0.0.jar. Assuming you downloaded 3.0.0. If any error message update your question. Also chose the *.jar option when downloading from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/files/violetumleditor/3.0.0/

Comment: did a fresh install with 3.0 again to try and the same thing.

Comment: _the .jar is located on my desktop, it should be found_ Just guessing: it should not be on the desktop but rather where you excute the `java -jar violetumleditor-3.0.0.jar`

Comment: using your console (or midnight commander... real computer scientist are not using Windows Explorer or that Finder OSX crap) navigate where you think you have the  *.jar file downloaded and execute: ls -la *. You must see the jar in the results, if not, you are in the wrong folder. You must either provide the absolute/relative path in the java command to the jar file or you must be in the same folder where your jar file is

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug open for this:
https://sourceforge.net/p/violet/bugs/69/
I personally don't think it would be fixed anytime soon.
I can recommend two alternative tools such as:
https://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/uml/uml-tool-for-mac/
https://gitmind.com